# jQueryValidate - Empty Password not stopping form

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a simple form using jQueryValidate:

```
 $("#frmMain").validate();
```

Leaving an empty Email will cause the validation to show and the form to stop, the password can strangely be left blank and the form submits.

What changes do I need to ensure the form doesn't submit when the password is empty, like the email does now:

```
 <form action="Login" id="frmMain" method="post" name="frmMain" role="form">

 <input class="input-validation-error form-control" data-msg-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-msg-required="The Email field is required." data-rule-email="true" data-rule-required="true" id="Email" name="Email" type="email" />

 <input autocomplete="off" class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The new password must be at least 8 characters long" data-val-length-max="15" data-val-length-min="8" data-val-required="Password is required" id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
```

Note, I set the default values for the validator:

```
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        if ($(form).valid()) {
            form.submit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use required on your form elements in html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code here is redundant and superfluous...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    if ($(form).valid()) {
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

- You don't need `if form.valid()` because the `submitHandler` only fires on a valid form.  (Your conditional `if` will never be `false`).
- You don't need `form.submit()` because this is the default behavior when the form is valid.  (the `form` action will fire)

That leaves nothing... so you don't need to specify a custom `submitHandler` for this case at all. (it  can be left out entirely as I did in jsFiddle below)

---

**Quote OP**:

> *"... the password can strangely be left blank and the form submits.  What changes do I need to ensure the form doesn't submit when the password is empty"*

What is so strange when no rule was specified that mandates the field be filled?  If you need to stop submit when the password is blank, you need the `required` rule.  Just compare the attributes from the email field to the password field and you'll see that `data-rule-required` is where the `required` rule is specified...

```
data-rule-required="true"
```

Add this attribute to the password field and now the field must be filled out.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/tv49y/**